# priority queue INSERTION and DISPLAY function in C++

Tags: c++, queue

Trying to implement priority queue insertion dev c++ IDE), i.e. before node with priority > new node's priority. Insertions from user seem to occur on command prompt but display function outputs only the first node. Why are other queue elements not being displayed? I am afraid they are not being inserted in first place that is why upon subsequent insertion of 10,20,30 and then deletion..it prints empty queue.. because queue only had 10..why?Please suggest.

Note: I have not included delete and main function, here in code, but it is there in the program, obviously..no run time exception occurs..compilation works fine. But no desired output.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef struct node{ //template would enable generic datatype
        int info,prn;
        node * link;
}node;

node * start = 0;
int item,pri;



    void insert(int item, int pri){
     node * newnode = new node;
     newnode-> info = item;
     newnode-> prn = pri;

     if(start == 0){//explicit check in insert if start is NULL.
              start = newnode;
              newnode->link = 0;
     }
     /*When you first run the program, start = 0 or NULL. You then say prev = start, 
so as a result prev = NULL. So when you try to access prev->link, there's an access violation.*/
     else{ 
          node * prev= start;
          node * temp = prev->link;
          while (temp!= 0){
                if(temp->prn > newnode->prn){
                        newnode -> link = prev -> link;
                        prev -> link = newnode;
                break;
                } 
                else{
                     if( temp->link == 0){
                              temp -> link = newnode;
                              newnode->link = 0;
                     break;
                     }
                } 
           prev = prev->link;                    
          }
     }
}
void display(){
     if(start == 0)
              cout<<"Empty priority queue\n";
     else{
          cout<<("The Contents of the List are: ");
          node *temp = start;   
          while(temp!=NULL){   //if we do while temp->link!=NULL, then last node won't print
                               cout<< temp->info;
                               cout<<" ---> ";
                               temp = temp->link;
          }
     }             
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When insert is called for the first time, start will be 0 but yet you will assign it to prev. On the next line, the one giving you the error you call `prev->link` so c++ crashes as you invoke a method on NULL(which invokes undefined behavior). You should add an explicit check in insert if `start` is NULL.

Answer (score 1):

When you first run the program, start = 0 or NULL. You then say prev = start, so as a result prev = NULL. So when you try to access prev->link, there's an access violation.